# Parse fixed-width .csv file

Tags: vb.net

i have .csv file which i need to parse. Its not delimted but fixed-with, ca you tell me what is the best way to parse such can of fail. This is the sample:

```
Object Name  IP Address Name    NE ID   NE Type/Release Partition Access Profile    Supervision State   
MS-POLT01    10.45.3.11 MS-POLT01   1   7302 ISAM IHUB R4.3 defaultPAP  Supervised  
TPO-POLT02   10.34.1.33/10.74..61   TPO-POLT02  10  7302 ISAM IHUB R4.3 defaultPAP  Supervised  
WPU-POLT02   10.70.8.21 WPU-POLT02  100 7302 ISAM IHUB R4.3 defaultPAP  Supervised  
MOV-POLT01   10.70.2.45 MOV-POLT01  101 7302 ISAM IHUB R4.3 defaultPAP  Supervised  
Results of 'EROS': 6 records found. Duration 0 s.
This query was executed by john
```

**EDIT** - for further discussions:

```
   Sub Main()

        Using MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.
    TextFieldParser("file.csv")

            MyReader.TextFieldType =
                Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
            MyReader.Delimiters = New String() {vbTab}
            Dim currentRow As String()
            'Loop through all of the fields in the file.  
            'If any lines are corrupt, report an error and continue parsing.  
            While Not MyReader.EndOfData
                Try
                    currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()

                    ' Debug.Print(String.Join(",", currentRow))
                    For Each currentField In currentRow
                        Debug.Print(currentField)
                    Next
                    ' Include code here to handle the row. 


                Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
                    Console.WriteLine("Line " & ex.Message & " is invalid.  Skipping")
                End Try
            End While
        End Using

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub
```

Comment: Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: thanks, my question is also how i would know this is tab delimeted file or fixed width?

Comment: Well - from what you pasted in, it does not look like fixed width at least, so if you cannot ask the provider, try both and see which gives the right result

Comment: you think if first lets say hundred line would go with delimted tab properly rest also should be tab delimteed right i mean once file is gouing to parse with tab delimted it is the formast of it right? P.S Fixed width is when there are diffrent spaces betwwen column;s values and how i would know max width number for each column?

Comment: You can only try, and test if the result is (seemingly) correct if you have no information about the file. There is no other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`TextFieldParser`-class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it  was exactly developed for this purpose:

[MSDN Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zezabash.aspx):

```
Using Reader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser("C:\TestFolder\test.log")
   Reader.TextFieldType = Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.FieldType.FixedWidth
   Reader.SetFieldWidths(5, 10, 11, -1)
   Dim currentRow As String()
   While Not Reader.EndOfData
      Try
         currentRow = Reader.ReadFields()
         Dim currentField As String 
         For Each currentField In currentRow
            MsgBox(currentField)
         Next 
      Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
         MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message &
         "is not valid and will be skipped.")
      End Try 
   End While 
End Using
```

Comment: my file is tab delimeted. Question is how to find out the file is fixed - width - i understand by it file is then diffrent lenghth betwn columns is that corret? How then i know if have no contact with provider what SetFieldWidths sizes i should put to diffrent columns?

Comment: @unknown: in your question you've stated that "its not delimted but fixed-with". It's difficult to provide a solution if you have no idea about the source file. You have to check it first. You could provide rules to determine the different file types. Then check the file againsts those rules first to detect the type before you start processing it. But the more different types are possible, the more likely are errors during processing

Comment: fixed-width means between columns are diffrent lengt right?

Comment: i used code from this msdn link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx . The file seems to be tab delimeted ok - but if you see  last line of my example from first post, there is line "Results for.." but my code didnt go to catch statment for why?

Comment: @unknown: you haven't posted your code, so how should i tell you why it doesn't go to the catch?

Comment: @unknown: if you use `vbTab` as delimiter you don't get an exception since even if the lines does not contain a tab the result is a `String()` with one field. Use the debugger.

Comment: how can i check that can you advice please? P.S Why then MSDN telling nothing about that ;/ ?

Comment: @unknown: i don't understand, you can check `currentRow.Length`, if it's `<> 6` you know that the line can be ignored because it' s not a _data_ line.

Comment: lenghth check is working, anyway why then is there catch statment if it will be never fulfiled?

Comment: @unknown: because if you use the `Delimiters` property then you have not  said how many columns you expect. So even if the line doesn't contain that delimiter it can be parsed and splitted to one field. Similar to why `"foo".Split(',')` does not raise an exception but an array with one string `"foo"`.

Comment: i fully understand it now but still have on mind why then microsoft put catch statment :O what situation in this case could raise it up?

Comment: @unknown: it's raised only under special circumstances(i don't know all), so for example with `SetFieldWidths` and the lines has less fields as provided. Or if you specify `HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes` but there is a line as `"foo,bah", "bah`, so without end-quote.

Comment: ok thanks for support wish you nice day. I am staying with lenght check